# Game Center leaderboard deprecated?

Tags: ios, game-center, sprite-kit

So im trying to implement Game center to my whack a mole game im working on and I cant find a replacement for GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate. Its deprecated in ios 7

Also if you guys know of a tutorial or sample code that will work with ios 7 could you please link it :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the alternative now is simply `GKGameCenterViewController` and `GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate`. `GKGameCenterViewController` allows you to specify a `leaderboardIdentifier` as of iOS 7. You can also specify a `viewState` of `GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards` so that it initially loads up with a view of the leaderboards. You can find some examples in this [GameKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/DisplayingGameCenterUserInterfaceElements/DisplayingGameCenterUserInterfaceElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH16-SW1).

Also, whilst [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW26) states that it's for iOS 6, it appears to be using `GKGameCenterViewController` and not `GKLeaderboardViewController`, so it might be fine on iOS 7.

Comment: Note that it should be GKGameCenterControllerDelegate not GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate.